# How do I call API hooks one at a time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am completely new to React and trying to figure this out, while still keeping it as simple as possible.

I have a wrapper functional component called `RestaurantMapWrapper` that is supposed to:

1. Get geolocation data from a hook called `usePosition`.
2. pass the longitude and latitude data into a hook called `useYelpHook`, which retrieves data on restaurants using the passed in latitude and longitude data.
3. Render the yelp data (automatically, without user input).

The problem is that `usePosition` does not get the location in time, so `useYelpHook` has nothing to work with. If I set `pos` to a default value, then `useYelpHook` is never called again.

How can I ensure that `useYelpHook` waits for `usePosition` before rendering? Does this have something to do with one hook being asynchronous?

```
export function RestaurantMapWrapper(props) {
    const { latitude, longitude, timestamp, accuracy, error, isLoadingMap } = usePosition();
    const pos = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }; //ends up being undefined since neither have been retreived yet
    const [{ data, isLoading }, setLoc] = useYelpHook(pos); //is there somewhere I could call setLoc?

    return <div>JSON.stringify({data})</div>;
```

```
export const useYelpHook = (initialLoc) => {
    const API_KEY = 'my api key';
    const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}` },
        params: {
            term: 'food',
            latitude: '0',
            longitude: '0',
            radius: '',
            sort_by: 'rating'
        }
    }

    const [data, setData] = useState({ businesses: [] });
    const [loc, setLoc] = useState(initialLoc);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
        config.params.latitude = loc.lat;
        config.params.longitude = loc.lng;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const result = await axios(`${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search`, config);
            setData(result.data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [loc])

    return [{ data, isLoading }, setLoc];
}
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const defaultSettings = {
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
    timeout: Infinity,
    maximumAge: 0,
};

export const usePosition = (settings = defaultSettings) => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({});
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoadingMap, setIsLoadingMap] = useState(true);

    const onChange = ({ coords, timestamp }) => {
        setPosition({
            latitude: coords.latitude,
            longitude: coords.longitude,
            accuracy: coords.accuracy,
            timestamp,
        });
    };

    const onError = (error) => {
        setError(error.message);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoadingMap(true);
        const geo = navigator.geolocation;
        if (!geo) {
            setError('Geolocation is not supported');
            return;
        }
        geo.getCurrentPosition(onChange, onError, settings);
        setIsLoadingMap(false);

    }, [settings]);

    return { ...position, error, isLoadingMap };
};
```

Comment: Run your yelp api call only when you receive proper coordinates. (ie. have an if statement check the validity of your coordinates in the yelp api's useEffect )

Comment: If I do that, then the first time useYelpHook is rendered nothing will show up. How would I render it again once proper coordinates are retrieved?

Comment: useYelpHook's useEffect runs every time the component renders and is triggered by the dependencies. You should pass loc directly into the useYelpHook useEffect instead of saving its initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useYelpHook's `useEffect` runs every time the component renders and is triggered by the dependencies. You should pass loc directly into the `useYelpHook` `useEffect` instead of saving its initial state.

```
export function RestaurantMapWrapper(props) {
    const { latitude, longitude, timestamp, accuracy, error, isLoadingMap } = usePosition();
    const pos = useMemo(() => ({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }), [latitude, longitude]); //ends up being undefined since neither have been retrieved yet
    const [{ data, isLoading }] = useYelpHook(pos);

    return <div>JSON.stringify({data})</div>;
```

```
const API_KEY = 'my api key';
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}` },
    params: {
        term: 'food',
        latitude: '0',
        longitude: '0',
        radius: '',
        sort_by: 'rating'
    }
}
export const useYelpHook = (loc) => {


    const [data, setData] = useState({ businesses: [] });
    //const [loc, setLoc] = useState(initialLoc);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
        /* return if loc is invalid */
        config.params.latitude = loc.lat;
        config.params.longitude = loc.lng;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const result = await axios(`${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search`, config);
            setData(result.data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [loc])

    return [{ data, isLoading }];
}
```

Note the useMemo and removal of initialLoc